# Compile error in Oracle APEX 5.1 classic report based on PLSQL function

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

In APEX 5.1, I have created a classic report based on PLSQL function that runs normally when I hard code values for the function parameters, but is returning an error "Parsing returned query result in 'ORA-20001: Query must begin with SELECT or WITH'" when using substitution strings for page items (":P340_CHANGE_FY", ":P340_CHANGE_ID") as parameters as below:

```
-- works as expected
return fddm_pkg.change_strategic_goal_sql(p_fy_id_in => 4, p_change_id_in => 64); 

-- page fails to save / compile with error stated above
return fddm_pkg.change_strategic_goal_sql(p_fy_id_in => :P340_CHANGE_FY, p_change_id_in => :P340_CHANGE_ID);
```

The values for the page items used as parameters are passed in to the page (and I've verified they are in session state); the two page items are also in "Page Items to Submit".

Logging in the function shows that when attempting to save the page, the page item values (the bind variables) are null. However, when doing some initial testing using bind variables in a report using generic column names, the proper SQL statement is generated.

I have tried explicitly converting the page items to the appropriate data type (number, in this case) using to_number() with the same result.

I apologize I am unable to provide a screen shot of the page as the application is being developed on an agency intranet and may not be published publicly.

Using Generic Column Names in production is not a viable option for me for this report, as the column names are dynamically determined.

Has anyone seen this type of problem? I appreciate any ideas.

Thank you,

Dave

Comment: Have you verified that `change_strategic_goal_sql` is being invoked? This would typically be done with a logging routine in the function. If you have this in place, have you verified that the correct values are being passed in? If you don't have such a routine in place, have look at logger: https://github.com/OraOpenSource/Logger

Comment: Thank you Dan. The function is properly invoked and returns the correct SQL statement when using static parameters; the problem I'm experiencing revolves around the use of page items - the page will not save because of the ORA-20001 error generated when APEX parses the function (I think that's what's happening).

Comment: I understand what you're saying. However, we're trying to troubleshoot an issue. Right now you're making some assumptions about what's happening when you use bind variables. Please re-read my previous comment and add some logging to your function so we can confirm your assumptions.

Comment: Thank you Dan - edited to reflect results of logging in the function.

Comment: upon further pondering, I think I'm beginning to understand that the function must return a valid SQL statement regardless of the inputs. Is that correct? Perhaps obvious, but not well documented.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When you think about it, the first step is to run your function, which should return an SQL query. The second step is to execute what's returned. So, if what's returned isn't valid, then you'll get an error.